# How to insert data in cassandra using Pig

Tags: cassandra, apache-pig

I am trying to copy data from a file in HDFS to a table in Cassandra using Pig. But the job fails with null pointer exception while storing the data in Cassandra. Can someone help me with this?

**Users table structure:**

CREATE TABLE users (
  user_id text PRIMARY KEY,
  age int,
  first text,
  last text
)

**My pig script**

1. A = load '/user/hduser/user.txt' using PigStorage(',') as (id:chararray,age:int,fname:chararray,lname:chararray);
2. C = foreach A GENERATE TOTUPLE(TOTUPLE('user_id',id)), TOTUPLE('age',age),TOTUPLE('first',fname),TOTUPLE('last',lname);
3. STORE C into 'cql://ram_keyspace/users' USING CqlStorage();

**Exception:**

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.cql3.CqlRecordWriter.(CqlRecordWriter.java:123)
    at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.cql3.CqlRecordWriter.(CqlRecordWriter.java:90)
    at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.cql3.CqlOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(CqlOutputFormat.java:76)
    at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.cql3.CqlOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(CqlOutputFormat.java:57)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(PigOutputFormat.java:84)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewDirectOutputCollector.(MapTask.java:627)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:753)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.cql3.CqlRecordWriter.(CqlRecordWriter.java:109)
    ... 12 more

Can someone who has used Pig with Cassandra help me fix this?

Comment: What version of Cassandra?

Comment: Cassandra version is 1.2.13

Answer (score 0):

You are using CqlStorage which requires you to specify the `output_query` which is a prepared statement that will be used to insert the data into the column family. The [DSE pig documentation](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/3.2/datastax_enterprise/ana/anaPigAccess.html) provides an example:

```
grunt> STORE insertformat INTO
   'cql://cql3ks/simple_table1?output_query=UPDATE+cql3ks.simple_table1+set+b+%3D+%3F'
   USING CqlStorage;
```